# Geodesic equation applied to halfplane model

Tags: differential-geometry

I have learned some things regarding connections and geodesic. And I want to apply this knowledge to the exercise: show that the vertical lines in the halfplane model are geodesics.

The metric is $\frac{\delta ^{ij}}{y^2}$, and the tangent vector has coordinates $(0,1)$ in the standard basis and I am therefore left to calculate the covariant derivative of the partial derivative wrt to y in direction of the same. However using the expression of the christoffel symbols in terms of the metric I get that $T^2_{22}=-2$ and not zero.

Where is my argument wrong?

Comment: I suggest you write down your calculation to see what is doing on (or it is hard for us to tell where did you go wrong). But I would **guess** that you are using the parametrization $\gamma(t) = (0, t)$, which is not parametrized as a constant speed curve.

Answer (score 0):

Using connections is slightly overkill for this one - a geodesic through $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is uniquely determined locally by its tangent vector, $v$. It follows that if there is a symmetry of your manifold that preserves:

i) the metric

ii) your point

iii) your tangent vector

then any geodesic through your point has to lie in the stabiliser of your symmetry.
In the present case, if the tangent vector $v$ is vertical, then reflection in the line $x = x_{0}$ satisfies all of the conditions above. So the axis of symmetry $x=x_{0}$ is a geodesic of the Poincaré half-plane.

Back to your original question, it is quickest to derive the Christoffel symbols from the Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\dot x ^2 + \dot y ^2 }{y^2} $. This yields

$\begin{align} 
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\dot x}{y^2}\bigg) &= 0 \\
\ddot y + \frac{\dot x^2 - \dot y^2}{y} &= 0\end{align} $

As the commenter remarks, your curve probably doesn't satisfy the second condition because it's not affinely parametrised. Nonetheless, it defines a non-affinely parametrised geodesic, as is obvious by substitution.